# MySql Data truncated for column 'value' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, database, exception

In my java web application, I am inserting some records into MySql db. I have a column name 'value' whose Field type is float. When I insert the following value 76.8653846153846  into db, it gives exception of Data truncated for column 'value' at row 1. I changed field type to Double but same  message. Any idea?

Field description:

[image]

Comment: What is the field description in the table where you are trying to insert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error 1265. Data truncated for column when trying to load data from txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764080/error-1265-data-truncated-for-column-when-trying-to-load-data-from-txt-file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) you must define your number type with the level of precision you require.

for your number 76.8653846153846 use

```
FLOAT(10,13)
```

The `13` being large enough to handle your `.8653846153846`

**[Edit]**

to alter your existing table execute this command substituting your table and column name for *mytable* and *mycolumn* respectively

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn FLOAT(10,13)
```

Comment: How to set that? I changed Length/Values value to (10,13) next type column but it generates '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near' error.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the database engine where the declared field's description  in the table  is not big enough to insert the complete data