# Python 2.7 - insert multiple values in MySql in one execution from dictionary key values

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, dictionary, insert

I am trying to make dynamic insert command into mysql, from dictionary values in one transaction but getting an error. Also I was wondering what is the most efficient way to perform this specific case (maybe my code is not optimal)?  I am using FOR since in some cases dictionary can be empty. Thanks

```
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(..........
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    varStatic="test"
    cust={'74.2': '54', '172.26': '76', '7': 'B9'}
    insertStatement='"""INSERT INTO customers (id,number,desc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""'
    for key in cust:
          insertStatement+=',('+key+','+cust[key]+','+varStatic+')'
    mycursor.execute(insertStatement)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"""REPLACE INTO customers (id,number,desc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",(74.2,54' at line 1

Comment: actually, not quite sure what is wrong but in the same time I do not have feeling that my code is based on best practice..

Comment: That does look like a syntax error. Maybe you could add a debug print statement something like `print insertStatement` and update your question with the output. Your using `'`'s so the `"""` ends up in your string.

Comment: I think that maybe this is because values KEY, VALUE, VARSTATIC are not quoted at all

Comment: `s = '"""%s %s"""' # '"""%s %s"""'` what you want is this:
`s = """%s %s""" % ('foo', 'bar') # 'foo bar'`

Comment: can you please put whole my statement how it should be defined as a solution in Answer?

Comment: Well I haven't worked out a whole answer. I just was noting that you are not building the string `insertStatement` correctly.  Which just a partial answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do something like this, but a little confused about how to optimize `for-loop` and `value`. If i can get rid of `append` or replace to `List Comprehensions`, then you can use `insertStatement += ("(%s,%s,%s),"*len(cust.items()))[:-1]`

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user="k",passwd="k",db="k")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
varStatic="test"
cust={'74.2': "54'", '172.26': '76', '7': 'B9'}
insertStatement= """INSERT INTO customers (id,number,desc) VALUES """
value = []
for k,v in cust.items():
    insertStatement += "(%s,%s,%s),"
    value.append(k)
    value.append(v)
    value.append(varStatic)

print(insertStatement[:-1],value)
try:
    mycursor.execute(insertStatement[:-1],value)
    mydb.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    mydb.rollback()
```

Comment: Hi its not working. This is for example output for two elements in dictionary. Something is not properly defined. This is what I am getting with Print statement.  INSERT INTO customers (id,number,desc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s),(%s,%s,%s) ['172.26.74.2111', '54.10.EC.0C.1D.6B', 'test', '172.26.74.112232', '54.10.EC.54.92.FD', 'test']

Comment: print(insertStatement[:-1])  returns INSERT INTO customers (id,numbers,desc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s),(%s,%s,%s)  this is really not correct

Comment: you should read this, and not recommend execute sql straight it will cause injection https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html @Dejan

Comment: I do not understand quite what you want to say? Are you suggesting to do insert one by one? your print of insert statement returns tis very strange and not correct format. Can you please correct it because answer is definetely not OK? print(insertStatement[:-1]) returns INSERT INTO customers (id,numbers,desc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s),(%s,%s,%s) .

Comment: `mycursor.execute()` will pass `['172.26.74.2111', '54.10.EC.0C.1D.6B', 'test', '172.26.74.112232', '54.10.EC.54.92.FD', 'test ']` into `INSERT INTO customers (id,numbers,desc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s),(%s,%s,%s) `. And you don't care about the data type, the function will automatically convert. Of course you can also execute your own sql, but you need to manually process the data to avoid SQL injection. btw, I will not post code I have never run, especially full code. @Dejande

Comment: Hi I run now and execute query, rows are not inserted in database and getting this as result : 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: @Dejan it seems the `id` you insert is too long. This is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089240/data-truncated-for-column

Comment: id is varchar(30). so it should import it. I think that issue is that your code is adding something additional on my statement for that column and it does not take only key value for the import. I suppose that is the issue.

Comment: I modifies now ID to be varchar 3000 and still getting the same error.

Comment: can you show your column, i want to try again. also i need the data which caused this error.

Comment: SHOW COLUMNS: 
id 

varchar(3000) 

YES 
 

NULL 
 


name 

varchar(50) 

YES 
 

NULL 
 


address 

varchar(50) 

YES 
 

NULL

Comment: data is very simple : varStatic="test"
cust={'172.26.74.2111': '54.10.EC.0C.1D.6B', '172.26.74.112232': '54.10.EC.54.92.FD'}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183938/discussion-between-kcorlidy-and-dejan).