# Laravel Collective drop-down to mysql in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'level'..

My guess is that Form::select should be used somehow differently, how?

```
// in my migration:
$table->enum('level', ['easy', 'hard']);

// in my controller Store function:
$tablee = new Tablee; // this is view file called Tablee.php
$tablee->level = $request->input('level');
$tablee->save();

// and part of my code in create.blade.php
<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('level', 'Please choose level')}}
  {{Form::select('level', ['easy' => 'easy', 'hard' => 'hard'], ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data truncated for column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089240/data-truncated-for-column)

Comment: no, all seems normal when I look thru phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of `Form::select` is the selected element.

```
public function select($name, $list = [], $selected = null, $options = [])
```

So you should change yours to be

```
{{ Form::select('level', ['easy' => 'easy', 'hard' => 'hard'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Comment: now I get: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'level' cannot be null (23000)

Comment: Do you have a default selection? The problem is because you are not setting the `level` to any value. Debug your `$request->input('level')` does it returns anything? Make sure that you have `level` in your `$fillable` array of your model.

Comment: Integrity error was because of my typo in Controller file, so the main issue is solved, thanks. I do not have an array in my model, please write in code what you mean, you see I am a beginner...

Comment: If it works than that's great. I was talking about the mass asignment part, you can read more about it in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment).