# Data truncated for column 'category'

Tags: mysql, sql, truncate

I am inserting data in WAMP server but following data is not inserting why?
It gives an error #1265 - Data truncated for column 'category'

```
INSERT INTO ecommerce.products (name, category) values ('pencil_box', 'stationery');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data truncated for column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089240/data-truncated-for-column)

Comment: "data truncated" means that you are inserting values for the column that don't fit in the column, for example if your column is char(10) and you insert a string of more than 10 characters. take a look at some of the similar questions

Comment: ideally you should tag a database product like MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, PostgreSQL or SQL Server (MSSQL).. As the SQL tag is about ANSI/ISO SQL standard .. Looking into the error message i belive you are using MySQL or MariaDB.