# Updating a Set Field Type with using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, set

I have a form with a series of checkboxes. The name of the checkboxes is `name="groups[]"`.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="value-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="value-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="value-3">
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="value-4">
```

I want to save the values submitted to a column named `groups` in a MySQL database. My Laravel update code is as follows:

```php
$record->groups = $attributes['groups'];
$record->save();
```

I have also tried:

```php
$record->groups = implode(',', $attributes['groups']);
$record->save();
```

Just in case it helps, the field details in the migration file is:

```php
$table->set('groups', ['value-1','value-2','value-3','value-4'])->nullable();
```

The error receiving is:

```
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'groups' at row 1 (SQL: update `table` set `groups` = ["value-1","value-2"] where `id` = 1)
```

Is my update code incorrect for Laravel and Set columns?

I tried Googling a lot, but because the term `set` is used in regular update queries, I'm not getting helpful results.

Edit: Added Table Structure

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) |
| groups | set('value-1','value2','value-3','value-4') |

Edit: Results of my attributes:

```php
array: 1 [▼
  "groups" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "value-1"
    1 => "value-2"
  ]
]
'''
```

Comment: could you add the result of `$attributes['groups']` in your question please?

Comment: Could you show us your table schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data truncated for column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089240/data-truncated-for-column)

Answer (score 0):

It ends up that the correct method to update a `set` type column is to implode the array into a comma separated string. I thought I tried this earlier, but it's working now, not actually sure why it wasn't before and is now. Here is the working update:

```php
$proposal->groups = implode(',', $attributes['groups']);
$proposal->save();
```